# Why does removing text from div cause this layout to break

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've removed text from the 9th `div` and got an unexpected result. The same happens while I remove text from other `div`s. I think the problem is in `display: inline-block`.

Here is my HTML and CSS example of the problem:

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">1</div>
<div class="relative">2</div>
<div class="relative">3</div>
<div class="relative">4</div>
<div class="relative">5</div>
<div class="relative">6</div>
<div class="relative">7</div>
<div class="relative">8</div>
<div class="relative"></div>
<div class="relative">10</div>
```

Comment: Vertical align top

Comment: First thing is why you want to add **div** if you nothing to display?
And if you still want to show that div then use **&nbsp;** if you don't have anything to show on that div element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because of the default vertical alignment at the `baseline` of inline-block elements. If there is no content, the alignment will be along the bottom of the element (= aligned with the text baseline of the others).

Use `vertical-align: top;` to avoid that:

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">1</div>
<div class="relative">2</div>
<div class="relative">3</div>
<div class="relative">4</div>
<div class="relative">5</div>
<div class="relative">6</div>
<div class="relative">7</div>
<div class="relative">8</div>
<div class="relative"></div>
<div class="relative">10</div>
```

Comment: Also because the elements are given a display of `inline-block` without content. If they had been given a display of `block` (even without content), the width and height would still be applied. But your answer seems to provide the solution without having to change the layout at all 

Comment: @SirExotic I wrote that in my answer "...of inline-block elements"